# Cache JSON response

Tags: jquery, json, html, geoip

I using some GeoIP service to place country flag on pages depends on country IP. And I need to cache JSON response for all pages on my site.

This code placed into `header.php`:

```
$.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function(data) {
  $('#flag').html("<a class='fancybox-inline int' href='#international'><img src='/images/flags/"+data.countryCode+".png'></a>");
  }
```

Is it possible to cache it with `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true })`? - seems to not work.

Or probably better to use HTML5 localStorage, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I also tried [JSONCache](https://github.com/kpuputti/JSONCache) plugin, but it did not work for me.

Comment: try to use $.ajax it has functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @Mac `$.getJSON` is an ajax request to a service that returns JSON specifically.  It's a shortcut method so you don't have to specify `type: 'JSON'` ergo - he is using ajax ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use localStorage like that:

```
var smartIp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('smartIp'));

if (!smartIp) $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function (data) {
    smartIp = localStorage.setItem('smartIp', JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ny55C/)

So, in your specific case, you should use this code in your `header.php` page:

```
var smartIp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('smartIp'));

if (!smartIp) $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function (data) {
    smartIp = localStorage.setItem('smartIp', JSON.stringify(data));
    $('#flag').html("<a class='fancybox-inline int' href='#international'><img src='/images/flags/" + data.countryCode + ".png'></a>");
});
else $('#flag').html("<a class='fancybox-inline int' href='#international'><img src='/images/flags/" + smartIp.countryCode + ".png'></a>");
```

Comment: @kasperTaeymans do you mean 'unecessary' instead? But localstorage can only store string, not javascript object so how would you do that without 'sringified' js object?

Comment: The max that you can save this way is 5mb per domain. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 8):

`$.getJSON()` is equivalent to

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json/ip_address',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){ // do something here }
});
```

In this form you can add additional parameters, such as `cache:true`, or any other $.ajax parameters you might need.

Comment: This one actually works too, but i prefer localStorage soution. Thanks